# ecommerce plugin with "buy for a friend" feature

Tags: plugin-recommendation, e-commerce

Does anyone know about any ecommerce plugin with a feature to send the purchase to a friend?

I need that feature but I cannot find any around. I would appreciate any information on this.

Comment: This question really isn't a good fit for the WPSE Q&A format; it will tend to lead to polling/opinion/etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one plugin called Certificate gift, basically does the job

Comment: Is there a link? Saying "I answered my own question" is not useful, please say how you answered it...

Answer (score 1):

By far the best and only e-commerce plugin I would use is Shopp (http://shopplugin.net/) I have used them all and not even one comes close. There is an addon for this as well as a "add to favorites" addon.

Comment: I checked and it doesn't have this feature, I feel really confortable using eshop, however this time is no enough

Comment: For future viewers, I would agree that Shopp might be suitable. The API allows customisation to the extent that the shipping address could be re-purposed to be 'friends delivery address' and additional fields for friend's name and a gift message can be added to the checkout with `shopp('checkout','customer-info')`

Answer (score 1):

I have used [WP e-Commerce](http://getshopped.org/) many times. Many features and great support. Check them out.